# Facebook url randomly unreachable

Tags: facebook, url, comments, facebook-like

I'm sure anyone who has worked with Facebook has encountered the url unreachable problem with the comments plugin and alike.

I managed to get around this initially by making urls go to the facebook app page rather the hosted page, figuring facebook would be able to find itself, and ammended the url with a query string which could internally redirect them to right content. For example "app.facebook.com/myApp/?myAppP=videos&myAppId=0001" would first of all load the facebook app page then redirect the iframe to show the videos page and play video 0001.

This worked great at first but seems to have become a little unpredictable. I have a list of different videos, all of which use the same url except that the "myAppId" is different so the correct video is loaded. However whilst the "comments" and "like" plugins work fine for about a 1/3 of them, the other 2/3 show the "url unreachable". I can see no correlation between the urls that work and those that don't. It seems completely random, but it is always the same one that do and don't work.

This has got me completely stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to disable sandbox on app settings